# How to get the GCP PROJECT_NUMBER from the PROJECT_ID or get the PROJECT_ID from the PROJECT_NUMBER with gcloud CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-resource-manager

Is there a way via `gcloud` to find `project_id` from `project_number`, or `project_number` from `project_id` without knowing one of the two?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to craft the perfect `gcloud` command which does NOT require the project to be the current project:

1. Get project id from project number 1234567890:

`gcloud projects list --filter PROJECT_NUMBER=1234567890 --format="value(PROJECT_ID)"`

2. Get project number from project id `pincopallo`:

`gcloud projects list --filter PROJECT_ID=pincopallo --format="value(PROJECT_NUMBER)"`

Comment: That worked for me, and should be marked as the correct answer by the OP.